# Getting value of xml file where local-name is equal to

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've a XML file like below, where there is a node 'cdm:markt' with a value. What I would like is to check if the value of that node is equal to something, if so then do something. {$property.markt} in xsl:variable market2 is a 'smarty' value that I get from another system. This variable I would like to check with the value that is in the local-name() markt.

But there is something strange happening. When I change this line '*<xsl:if test="*[local-name() = 'markt'] = $market2">*' into '*<xsl:if test="*[local-name() = 'markt'] = 'itv'">*' it works. When I check on the XSL:variable it doesn't work anymore. Maybe there is somebody that found the solution for me how to solve this issue?

The values for market2 can be for examplce itv, auto, wonen. So it is not just one value that I've to check. That's why I would like the check the variable with the value of the node in de XML file.

**Example XSLT code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="rss/channel">
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <xsl:call-template name="actie_row"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="actie_row">
        <!-- Start variabelen ophalen -->
        <xsl:variable name="market2">{$property.markt}</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="actie_markt"><xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'markt']"/></xsl:variable>
        <!-- Einde variabelen ophalen -->

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrapper" summary="">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" summary="">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="column" class="font" style="padding-bottom:40px;border-bottom:3px solid #f4f4f4;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$market2"/> / 
                                <xsl:value-of select="$actie_markt"/> / 
                                <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name() = 'markt']"/> / 
                                <xsl:if test="*[local-name() = 'markt'] = $market2">
                                    / test
                                </xsl:if>
                                <br/>
                                ## <xsl:value-of select="title"/> / <xsl:value-of select="description"/> / <xsl:value-of select="markt"/> ##
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Example XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <description/>
    <title>Consumentenacties</title>
    <pubDate>Fri, 14 Jan 2022 13:30:20 GMT</pubDate>
    <item>
      <title>NLZiet</title>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://</guid>
      <category>Acties</category>
      <pubDate>Fri, 14 Jan 2022 14:38:53 GMT</pubDate>
      <cdm:markt xmlns:cdm="http://">sim</cdm:markt>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>NLZiet</title>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://</guid>
      <category>Acties</category>
      <pubDate>Fri, 14 Jan 2022 13:32:08 GMT</pubDate>
      <cdm:markt xmlns:cdm="http://">itv</cdm:markt>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>Ongevallendekking</title>
      <guid isPermaLink="true">http://</guid>
      <category>Acties</category>
      <pubDate>Fri, 14 Jan 2022 15:38:08 GMT</pubDate>
      <cdm:markt xmlns:cdm="http://">auto</cdm:markt>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a hack like `*[local-name() = 'markt']`, declare the same namespace in your stylesheet and use the expanded name, with prefix.

Here is a **simplified** example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/rss">
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="channel/item">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="cdm:markt" xmlns:cdm="http://"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will produce:

**Result (rendered)**

[image]